# Why is a json string reaching a restful service in different format?

Tags: java, jquery, rest

I want to send the json string to restful services using post method.  It is being sent, but the data received at the server side has a different format. What have I missed?

This is my restful service in java

```
@Path("/CommonDemo")
public class CommonDemo 
{   
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String result(String user)throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    System.out.println(user);
     return user;
}
```

}

I am calling the above service using the jquery as follows.

```
   var url = "http://localhost:8080/Snefocare/CommonDemo";
   var user="{'serviceInfo': [{'name':'All'}]}"; 

 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
      url: url,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data:{'user':user},
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         alert('date'+data);

     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert('error: ' + textStatus +' ERROR:'+ errorThrown);
     }
 });
```

I am sending it with this statement

```
var user="{'serviceInfo': [{'name':'All'}]}";
```

and in the restful service, I am seeing it as

```
user=%7B'serviceInfo'%3A+%5B%7B'name'%3A'All'%7D%5D%7D
```

I do not know why the % and other digits have been added.

Comment: dont pass json format directly in url. you can use encodeURIComponent() function to encode your url with json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try
 data:JSON.stringify(user),
 it will works.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know why the % and other digits have been added.

The % and digits is URL encoding.  Certain characters (actually, bytes) are being replaced with `%xx` where `xx` is a pair of hex digits representing the byte.

The problem is that your client-side is passing a Javascript object with an attribute that is a JSON string.  You should be stringifying it, as described by @ishwar.

The [jquery.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says:

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. ...

So what is happening is that your object is being converted to a URL query string ... complete with URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `user` variable is not legal JSON - it's using the wrong string terminator (JSON requires double quotes around keys and strings, not single quotes).

Secondly, it's being automatically converted into `x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding with `%xx` substitution because you haven't told jQuery not to.

Try the following to have a "plain JS object" posted in the *body* of an AJAX POST request:

```
var user= {'serviceInfo': [{'name': 'All'}]};  // JS object literal

$.ajax({
    type: POST,
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    data: JSON.stringify(user), // defer encoding to JSON until here
    processData: false,         // and do not URL encode the data
    ...
});
```